# Material gets applied to everything that was previously its own object

Tags: materials

Basically I made a diffuse, normal and roughness map following this guide:https://artisticrender.com/how-to-bake-textures-in-blender/ and when I try to assign these maps to the mesh by removing all material slots and creating a new material, they are applied to everything that was an object before I hit ctrl + J. [image] I need the pistol on the right to look like the pistol on the left but I don't get how to apply the texture to the entire mesh and not as if it was all separate objects.

Comment: hello please pack your images and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/ (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate)

Comment: Hope i did it right: https://pasteall.org/blend/e438b29fc10043d88d2405c52e7aa927

Comment: so you want to mix all the textures into one? In that case you need to look into how to bake. As you have materials with glossiness you'll need several maps

Comment: I have baked the maps but right now I am just trying to get the base color to work and the problem is that the maps are applied to every part of the mesh and not as one thing. For example: when I try to apply the diffuse map to the mesh, the red dots that are only supposed to be on the safety are applied to every component of the gun. The same goes for every part of the diffuse map

Comment: oh ok I get your problem, you need to delete the former UV Map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete your former UV map, otherwise the new one won't be taken into account:

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks